# Media module and views

Tags: media

I am using Media module on a Drupal 7 installation and have created a content type called Media. I then used the Multimedia asset of the Media module, so users can upload both images and videos.

I now want to create a view with the latest videos and also latest photos, but there is not anything on the filter to select a video (or photo). How can I add such a filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

- Create a new taxonomy vocabulary called 'Media Type' with terms 'Image' and 'Video.'
- Add a taxonomy field to your Media content type.
- Add a taxonomy field to your view (hidden/exposed/however you'd like)

You'll then be able to filter by the value of the taxonomy field.